# Node Background Threads - When Do These Get Created?

Tags: multithreading, node.js, express

I've been doing a fair amount of work with Node lately, trying to build a system which has certain characteristics, one of which is non-blocking / parallelism - a Node strong suit, as I understand it.

What I don't fully understand is *when* a separate thread is spun off to handle some processing.  I'm pretty sue this happens on a function call/call back, but certainly not all of them.

In my specific case, it's an Express based app.  At app start-up it does several things including instantiating a RabbitMQ based "bus", an object with a method which will write to the bus (objA) and object which will subscribe to the bus and process messages coming across it (objB).

objA will write to the bus inside an express callback

```
app.put((req,res) => {
    objA.methodWhichWritesToBus();
});
```

I believe at this point, that `objA.methodWhichWritesToBus` is executed in a background/worker thread - whatever you call it, not on the main event loop.

Is that the only point at which this sort of thing happens?  `methodWhichWritesToBus` is IO instensive (it calls an elastic search service on another box and brings back 10's to 100's of thousands of records) with lots of chained promises etc., but none of that gets split off, does it?

How about the fact that the obj on which the method is called is instantiated *outside* the Express callback - does that affect the parallel-ism?

Finally, are the ways to effect/force a method etc to "run in the background"?

I've been noodling this, testing it, for awhile now but all on one machine so it's difficult to tell what's going on.

Who can clarify this for me?

Comment: You do not need to notion of threads to understand the semantics of node.js. As long as you think in terms of threads you got it wrong.

Comment: @usr I'm pretty sure you've misunderstood my question but, all the same, the point was to clarify things for me, so please do.

Comment: If I misunderstood I do not yet see how. You think that concurrency in node happens through threads. This is not the case. Logically, there is a single thread processing events and no operations happens outside of the event loop. methodWhichWritesToBus probably only starts the logn-running operation and returns very quickly.

Comment: "Logically" there is a single-thread? Let's talk about *actually*... http://rickgaribay.net/archive/2012/01/28/node-is-not-single-threaded.aspx

Comment: Maybe this helps: JavaScript code only runs on a single thread (everything else would imply a host of race conditions). And most IO does not even consume any "background" thread while it is running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pre-answer: this is a topic best learned by going and reading, doing coding exercises to solidify your understanding, and working with the technology in a significant way. You're not going to "get it" based on a Q&A format. That said...

> What I don't fully understand is when a separate thread is spun off to handle some processing.

Never, sort of. "Processing" as in the computation that happens in your javascript program, happens in the main event loop thread. End of story. However, waiting on I/O to come back from the OS is not considered "processing" so there are various queues managed by node and the OS to track pending I/O requests and invoke callbacks when data is ready. There are a handful of threads node uses internally to manage this stuff with the OS, but from your program's perspective, those threads are irrelevant. Your program can ask node to do some IO, then your program keeps running in parallel, and when the I/O is done, node will eventually invoke the callback in the main event loop and you can process the results.

> I believe at this point, that objA.methodWhichWritesToBus is executed in a background/worker thread - whatever you call it, not on the main event loop.

You call it "asynchronously" and it happens whenever you do IO, including filesystem calls, networking, or child processes. Which is to say, quite a lot.

> How about the fact that the obj on which the method is called is instantiated outside the Express callback - does that affect the parallel-ism?

Nope.

> Finally, are the ways to effect/force a method etc to "run in the background"?

Generally I/O is done asynchronously by default, so no you don't normally need to force anything to run in the background. It's baked into the node design by way of the node core APIs themselves. However, there are ways to delay synchronous processing to a future event loop using `setImmediate`, `setTimeout`, or `process.nextTick`. I explain these in some detail in my blog post [setTimeout and friends](http://peterlyons.com/problog/2014/03/settimeout-and-friends).

More precisely, all networking is asynchronous. End of story. Specifically, the APIs in node core that are available are all asynchronous, and there's simply no synchronous API available in node. For filesystem IO and child processes, there are both synchronous and asynchronous APIs, but the synchronous APIs must only be used under special limited circumstances, and if you don't know confidently that it's OK in this specific case to make a synchronous IO API call, you should use the asynchronous API so you don't break the lynchpin that makes node perform as it does.

Comment: First, thanks for a real answer.  You mention "child process(es)" in a few places as things that can/may run asynchronously.  What qualifies as a child process? Do you mean this? http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html

Comment: Yes, I mean child process in the unix sense of your node program is a process within the OS and process can spawn subprocesses called "child processes" within a tree that enforces permissions. Node's child_process module is the API that exposes this. They can be both synchronous (start it, wait while it runs, then resume when its done), or asynchronous (start it, keep working in parallel while it runs, let me know when it's done). People often use this for image processing with graphicsmagick, multimedia processing, misc helper programs not written for node, etc.